# Is there a way to read the Keyboard Modifier Keys such as ALT or CTRL in DOS-based programs?

Tags: keyboard, dos, x86-16, basic, turbo-basic

I do know that you might poll the keyboard buffer to get the Modifier Keys such as <kbd>ALT</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>. But even in old DOS Programs there was an action whenever I just pressed these keys (eg. to change the Color of the MENU buttons by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>). Is there a way in DOS to get these Keys? How is this to be done? I think in BASIC there would be no solution although BASIC has some `ON KEY()` event handler available. Any recommendations or advises to this question are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the *KeyboardStatusFlags* at linear address 1047 in the BIOS data area. For the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key you examine bit 3, and for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key you examine bit 2. Next QBASIC program does exactly that:

```
DEF SEG = 0
DO
  IF PEEK(1047) AND 8 THEN
    PRINT "ALT is pressed"
    EXIT DO
  ELSEIF PEEK(1047) AND 4 THEN
    PRINT "CTRL is pressed"
    EXIT DO
  END IF
LOOP
```

### Answering a comment

> Is there also a way to get the KEY Pressed (ASCII VALUE) by peeking an address?

Again you can find this info in the keyboard buffer (a circular buffer). BIOS maintains a word-sized pointer to the place where the next available key is stored (HEAD), and a word-sized pointer to the place behind where the most recently buffered key is stored (TAIL). If HEAD equals TAIL, then the keyboard buffer is empty. `INKEY$` would return an empty string in this case.

```
Head% = PEEK(1050) + 256 * PEEK(1051)
Tail% = PEEK(1052) + 256 * PEEK(1053)
IF Head% <> Tail% THEN
  Ascii% = PEEK(1024 + Head%)
  Scan% = PEEK(1024 + Head% + 1)
ELSE
  Ascii% = 0
  Scan% = 0
END IF
```

The 'advantage' of above code is that you can **preview** what key (if any) is available next in the keyboard buffer. The key is not removed. `INKEY$` can give the same info **but will remove the key also**.

Comment: One more question: Is there also a way to get the KEY Pressed (ASCII VALUE) by peeking an address? This polling routine is really great!

Comment: Your 'other solution' in the second answer, gives a scancode from port 60h. That's certainly not an ASCII code! You can get that very easily via `Scan% = INP(&H60)` `IF Scan% > 127 THEN Scan% = 0` No need for assembly.

Comment: I should point out that I didn't actually write that code for this answer. I answered another question about converting some assembly for one variant of basic to turbo basic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all that good advices, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is the Answer of Michael Petch: [Stackoverflow-get ASCII VALUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63334114/how-can-i-include-a-asm-program-into-my-turbo-basic-program)

```
; Assemble with nasm -f bin getkeyh.asm -o getkeyh.com

GetKeyH:
    push bp
    mov  bp, sp
    les  bx, [bp+6]            ; ES:BX = address of variable to return value in
                               ; [bp+0] is where BP was pushed
                               ; [bp+2] is where the 32-bit far return address is
                               ; [bp+6] is where last parameter is
                               ; Parameters are pushed on stack left to right
                               ; like pascal calling convention.

    in   al,60h                ; Get scancode from keyboard
    xchg dx,ax
    xor  ax,ax                 ; assume no key (AX=0)
    test dl,10000000b          ; is it key up event?
    jnz  short getkeyhD        ;     if it is return 0 (in AX)
    mov  al, dl                ; Otherwise keydown, AX = scan code
getkeyhD:
    mov  [es:bx], ax           ; Update variable with scancode so BASIC can read it.
    pop bp
```

A version that can be used with MASM/JWASM/Turbo Assembler:

```
; Assemble and link with Turbo Assembler to getkeyh.com file with: 
; tasm getkeyh.asm
; tlink /t getkeyh
;
; You can use JWASM a MASM clone available on MacOS/Linux/Windows to
; build getkeyh.com . You can use:
; jwasm -bin -Fo=getkeyh.com -0 getkeyh.asm
;
; -0 generates code that can run on 8088/8086 processors
; -1 for 186+ processors
; -2 for 286+ processors
;
; MASM 6.0+ and Segmented Linker LINK.EXE (5.60) can generate getkeyh.com:
; masm getkeyh.asm;
; link /t getkeyh,getkeyh.com;
;
; MASM5.x doesn't support ".model tiny" you have to use ".model small"
; and use LINK.EXE 5.60:
; masm getkeyh.asm;
; link /t getkeyh,getkeyh.com;
 
.model tiny                    ; We will generate a COM file
 
.code
org 100h                       ; COM Programs have an ORG 100h
 
GetKeyH PROC
    push bp
    mov  bp, sp
    les  bx, [bp+6]            ; ES:BX = address of variable to return value in
                               ; [bp+0] is where BP was pushed
                               ; [bp+2] is where the 32-bit far return address is
                               ; [bp+6] is where last parameter is
                               ; Parameters are pushed on stack left to right
                               ; like pascal calling convention.
 
    in   al,60h                ; Get scancode from keyboard
    xchg dx,ax
    xor  ax,ax                 ; assume no key (AX=0)
    test dl,10000000b          ; is it key up event?
    jnz  short getkeyhD        ;     if it is return 0 (in AX)
    mov  al, dl                ; Otherwise keydown, AX = scan code
getkeyhD:
    mov  es:[bx], ax           ; Update var with scancode so Turbo Basic can read it
    pop bp                     ; Do not use `RET`, Turbo Basic will return for us
GetKeyH ENDP
 
END GetKeyH                    ; Entrypoint is GetKeyH
```

with the Turbo Basic Program part:

```
SUB GetKeyH INLINE
    $INLINE "getkeyh.com"
END SUB

CLS
DO
    LOCATE 10, 10
    Call GetKeyH (scancode%)
    PRINT "Key = "; HEX$(scancode%); "    "
LOOP UNTIL INKEY$ = CHR$(27)

END
```