# How can I include a ASM program into my Turbo Basic Program?

Tags: assembly, keyboard, dos, x86-16, turbo-basic

I found this ASM routine to get the key pressed. [ASM routine to get key pressed](http://www.fysnet.net/kbuffio.htm) Now I would like to include it to a Turbo Basic routine, but do not know how to do this. Can anyone here tell me how it is be done? THanks

EDIT: I found a way: $INLINE, but How can I convert my asm code to Machine Language, that I can inline it into my basic program?

EDIT: I had no success in putting this QBASIC with Asm Code in it into an TURBO BASIC Program. I would be thankful for any help how to do it:

```
DECLARE FUNCTION GetKeyH% ()

CLS
DO
  LOCATE 10, 10
  PRINT "Key = "; HEX$(GetKeyH%); "    "
LOOP UNTIL INKEY$ = CHR$(27)
END
```

and the ASM PART:

```
Dosseg
.model medium, basic
.286
.stack
.code
Even
           public    getkeyh            ; make getkeyh public
getkeyh    proc far basic uses bp dx    ; save registers

           in   al,60h
           xchg dx,ax
           xor  ax,ax                   ; assume no key
           test dl,10000000b
           jnz  short getkeyhD
           mov  al,dl
getkeyhD:  ret
getkeyh    endp                         ; end of procedure
           end                          ; end of assembly code
```

[image]

EDIT: THANKS a lot to the Answer of Mr Michael Petch below. Moreover I could see that this ASM routine is also a solution to [CTL and ALT KEYS pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206937/is-there-a-way-to-read-the-keyboard-modifier-key-such-as-alt-or-ctrl-in-dos-base)

Comment: This question make you seem like a time-traveler from 30 years ago. What resources do you have available for Turbo Basic? What have you searched for? What have you tried? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like showing a [mcve] of your own attempt.

Comment: Yes I do know that this is a topic 30 years ago, I thought I could add some ASM lines directly into the program with include or poke. So this question is for only older Freaks who still have learned the basics 30 years ago.

Comment: You can use an assembler like NASM to generate the machine code and then you just convert that to the bytes in the inline assembly statement. You can also take the bytes in the inline assembly and generate a binary file and view a disassembly to understand what the code in the example does. `&H` just means hex value and the 2 digits after are the hex digits.

Comment: You can also create COM program and have them included into the basic program with the `$INLINE` statement. This might be more convenient as you don't need to convert between the machine code to bytes and vice versa. The Inline assembly it just read from a simple DOS COM program. The section Assembly Language Interface in Appendix C of the documentation gives a lot of additional info.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your advice is a great step ahead!

Comment: @MichaelPetch One More Q: I have done the first.asm file. Must I do the loader ld also when I want to put the HEX BYTES in the inline statement? Do I assume correctly that I have only to put  the `first.o` file after asm into the INLINE HEX BYTES?

Comment: You can't load object files. You need to create a COM program from the object file. Which assembler are you using?

Comment: @MichaelPetch NASM under Ubuntu - but want 286 code

Comment: Then you can just output to BIN format directly. `nasm -f bin first.asm -o first.com` . At the top of first.asm put `org 0x100` and then the assembly code. whatever you do don't put a `ret` at the end. The bytes will be loaded into the turbo basic program directly and turbo basic will supply the mechanism to return to the caller. The `org 0x100` isn't really necessary since inline can't use absolute memory locations in the com program

Comment: @MichaelPetch Dear friend, thank you very very much. It works great and I learnt a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it would work as expected. I will write up an answer a bit later today when I get some time. I also put up a version of the code that can be built with turbo assembler/JWASM/(MASM5+ and Link 5.60): https://pastebin.com/raw/6d50HsxG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DEBUG.COM` to enter the Assembly code, then perform a hexadecimal dump to get the machine code.

It looks like this:

```
D:\>DEBUG
-A 100
0ABD:0100 IN AL,60
0ABD:0102 XCHG DX,AX
0ABD:0103 XOR AX,AX
0ABD:0105 TEST DL,80
0ABD:0108 JNZ 10C
0ABD:010A MOV AL,DL
0ABD:010C RET
0ABD:010D
-R CX
CX 0000  :D
-N KEY.COM
-W
Writing 000D bytes
-Q

D:\>HEXDUMP KEY.COM
00000000    E4  60  92  31  C0  F6  C2  80  75  02  88  D0  C3                  .`.1....u....

D:\>
```

So that now you can encapsulate each machine code with `$INLINE`.

```
$INLINE &HE4, &H60, &H92, &H31, &HC0, &HF6, &HC2, &H80, &H75, &H02, &H88, &HD0
```

As suggested by @Michael Petch, do not include the last machine code (`&HC3`) in your `$INLINE` metastatement.

Note: While `HEXDUMP.EXE` is my own program, you can easily find any hex editor available on the Internet to view the content of a binary file.